# PhantomJS not rendering javascript like chrome

Tags: python, phantomjs, web-crawler

I am tring to get the JSON from this address http://www.yesplanet.co.il/presentationsJSON

When I am using a normal browser like chrome, it seems like the browser makes the first http request to http://www.yesplanet.co.il/presentationsJSON, then renders some js which creates a new cookie called `rbzid`, and finally makes a second http request to http://www.yesplanet.co.il/presentationsJSON.

Only then the respones' body contains the desired JSON

Here are some screenshots from Fiddler:
First request:
[image]

and the second:
[image]

However, when I try loading this page using PhantomJS, it only makes the first request, and never provides the JSON

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://www.yesplanet.co.il/presentationsJSON")
print driver.page_source
```

prints this:

```
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body><script>window.rbzns = {fiftyeightkb: 1800000, days_in_week : 7};</script><script>var h9U={'L6':function(U,b){return U!=b;},'t6':function(U,b){return U|b;},'R6':function(U,b){return U>>>b;},'l2':function(U,b){return U===b;},'T7H':(function(L7H){return (function(C7H,r7H){return (function(W7H){return {v7H:W7H};})(function(B7H){var R7H,E7H=0;for(var q7H=C7H;E7H<B7H["length"];E7H++){var X7H=r7H(B7H,E7H);R7H=E7H===0?X7H:R7H^X7H;}return R7H?q7H:!q7H;});})((function(c7H,J7H,P7H,f7H){var F7H=32;return c7H(L7H,F7H)-f7H(J7H,P7H)>F7H;})(parseInt,Date,(function(J7H){return (''+J7H)["substring"](1,(J7H+'')["length"]-1);})('_getTime2'),function(J7H,P7H){return new J7H()[P7H]();}),function(B7H,E7H){var O7H=parseInt(B7H["charAt"](E7H),16)["toString"](2);return O7H["charAt"](O7H["length"]-1);});})('6ia8u0v00'),'n2':function(U,b){return U==b;},'x2':function(U,b){return U&b;},'N0':function(U,b){return U&b;},'p6':function(U,b){return U|b;},'c3':function(U,b){return U<b;},'g5':function(U,b){return U<<b;},'W5':function(U,b){return U>b;},'e2':function(U,b){return U!==b;},'j0':function(U,b){return U<b;},'e1':function(U,b){return U<b;},'T6':function(U,b,D,k){return U|b|D|k;},'s6':function(U,b){return U<b;},'G7':function(U,b){return U>>b;},'k7':function(U,b){return U<b;},'p2':function(U,b){return U<b;},'C3':function(U,b){return U>b;},'B7':function(U,b){return U<<b;},'k5H':"push",'K2':function(U,b){return U&b;},'h0':function(U,b){return U<=b;},'C7':function(U,b){return U>>b;},'O1':"getTimezoneOffset",'S3':function(U,b){return U<b;},'z7':function(U,b){return U<=b;},'X3':function(U,b){return U<b;},'a5':function(U,b){return U&b;},'w3':function(U,b){return U|b;},'T7':function(U,b){return U<b;},'P6':function(U,b){return U%b;},'M0':function(U,b){return U&b;},'Y2':function(U,b){return U===b;},'R0':function(U,b){return U&b;},'u3':function(U,b){return U|b;},'k1':function(U,b){return U<b;},'J7':function(U,b){return U<<b;},'j6':function(U,b,D,k){return U|b|D|k;},'U2':function(U,b){return U!==b;},'I0':function(U,b){return U<=b;},'l5':function(U,b){return U&b;},'U3':function(U,b){return U==b;},'t3':function(U,b){return U<=b;},'r5':function(U,b){return U===b;},'e5':function(U,b){return U&b;},'F2':function(U,b){return U&b;},'z6':function(U,b){return U|b;},'B3':function(U,b){return U>=b;},'N7':function(U,b){return U==b;},'c7':function(U,b){return U<<b;},'s3':function(U,b){return U&b;},'d2H':"get",'p7':function(U,b){return U<<b;},'h3':function(U,b){return U!=b;},'U1':function(U,b){return U>>>b;},'x6':function(U,b){return U&b;},'M7':function(U,b){return U<<b;},'M6':function(U,b){return U|b;},'J3':function(U,b){return U&b;},'a2':function(U,b){return U-b;},'w5':function(U,b){return U<=b;},'n5':function(U,b){return U|b;},'D3':function(U,b){return U&b;},'K5':function(U,b){return U>>>b;},'u0':function(U,b,D,k){return U^b^D^k;},'m6':function(U,b,D){return U|b|D;},'X7':function(U,b){return U&b;},'s7':function(U,b){return U!=b;},'E5':function(U,b){return U&b;},'q6':function(U,b){return U&b;},'M3':function(U,b){return U>=b;},'Q3':function(U,b){return U>=b;},'f2':function(U,b){return U|b;},'W2':function(U,b){return U|b;},'P0':function(U,b){return U&b;},'I9':"undefined",'i6':function(U,b){return U<b;},'O0':function(U,b){return U<=b;},'Y5':function(U,b){return U&b;},'u7':function(U,b){return U>>b;},'k6':function(U,b){return U|b;},'j7':function(U,b){return U>>b;},'G0':function(U,b){return U>=b;},'d6':function(U,b){return U&b;},'r2':function(U,b){return U&b;},'S5':function(U,b){return U<=b;},'p2H':"Fingerprint",'Q8':"charCodeAt",'q0':function(U,b){return U<=b;},'n1':function(U,b){return U===b;},'T3':function(U,b){return U&b;},'l1':function(U,b){return U in b;},'j3':function(U,b){return U>b;},'p1':function(U,b){return U<b;},'d2':function(U,b){return U&b;},'V0':function(U,b){return U&b;},'L0':function(U,b){return U<=b;},'l9':"join",'t7':function(U,b){return U&b;},'H5':function(U,b){return U<<b;},'Y8':"plugins",'E2':function(U,b){return U&b;},'k2':function(U,b){return U===b;},'v2':function(U,b){return U<b;},'b5':function(U,b){return U<<b;},'f5':function(U,b){return U===b;},'Y1':function(U,b){return U*b;},'F5':function(U,b){return U>>>b;},'h7':function(U,b){return U>>b;},'D8':"-",'U2H':"function",'Q0':function(U,b){return U&b;},'v5':function(U,b){return U>>>b;},'R9':"test",'D0':function(U,b){return U&b;}};var bsig;try{(function(U,b,D){var k=h9U.T7H.v7H("543")?"temp":"amd",Q=h9U.T7H.v7H("1c")?"exports":"n";h9U.I9!==typeof module&&module[Q]?module[Q]=D():h9U.U2H===typeof define&&define[k]?define(D):b[U]=D();})(h9U.p2H,this,function(){var I=h9U.T7H.v7H("f1")?"D":"getContext",A=h9U.T7H.v7H("38")?"createElement":"Fingerprint",s=h9U.T7H.v7H("5fd")?"userAgent":"encoded",t=h9U.T7H.v7H("5b57")?"getRegularPluginsString":"ie_activex",O=h9U.T7H.v7H("d8db")?"screen_orientation":"length",B=h9U.T7H.v7H("d8")?"screen_resolution":"result",V="hasher",f=h9U.T7H.v7H("65")?null:"cookie",C="map",N=function(j){var m=h9U.T7H.v7H("cf7")?"getContext":"call";var u=h9U.T7H.v7H("cdd")?"counter_x":"each";var T,Z;T=Array.prototype.forEach;Z=Array.prototype.map;this[u]=function(U,b,D){var k="l2";var Q="hasOwnProperty";var H=h9U.T7H.v7H("a2c")?31:"e2";var y=h9U.T7H.v7H("2eb")?"p2":32768;var o="forEach";var M="k2";var h="U2";if(h9U[h](null,U))if(T&&h9U[M](U[o],T))U[o](b,D);else if(U.length===+U.length)for(var p=0,K=U.length;h9U[y](p,K)&&h9U[H](b[m](D,U[p],p,U),{});p++);else for(p in U)if(U[Q](p)&&h9U[k](b[m](D,U[p],p,U),{}))break;};this[C]=h9U.T7H.v7H("a41")?function(k,Q,H){var y=h9U.T7H.v7H("134")?61:"Y2";var o="n2";var M=[];if(h9U[o](f,k))return M;if(Z&&h9U[y](k[C],Z))return k[C](Q,H);this[u](k,function(U,b,D){M[M.length]=Q[m](H,U,b,D);});return M;}:8388608;"object"==typeof j?(this[V]=h9U.T7H.v7H("fa12")?"atob":j[V],this[B]=j[B],this[O]=h9U.T7H.v7H("382")?j[O]:"hasher",this.canvas=j.canvas,this[t]=h9U.T7H.v7H("ec4")?"canvas":j[t]):"function"==typeof j&&(this[V]=j);};N.prototype={get:function(){var U="murmurhash3_32_gc",b=h9U.T7H.v7H("6ce1")?"getCanvasFingerprint":"outerWidth",D="isCanvasSupported",k="getPluginsString",Q="doNotTrack",H="platform",y="cpuClass",o="openDatabase",M="addBehavior",h="body",p=h9U.T7H.v7H("86ff")?"pageXOffset":"indexedDB",K=h9U.T7H.v7H("3d31")?"hasLocalStorage":"hasLocalStorage",j="hasSessionStorage",m=h9U.T7H.v7H("5a3")?"window":"getScreenResolution",u="colorDepth",T="language",Z=[];Z[h9U.k5H](navigator[s]);Z[h9U.k5H](navigator[T]);Z[h9U.k5H](screen[u]);this[B]&&"undefined"!==typeof this[m]()&&Z[h9U.k5H](this[m]()[h9U.l9]("x"));Z[h9U.k5H]((new Date)[h9U.O1]());Z[h9U.k5H](this[j]());Z[h9U.k5H](this[K]());Z[h9U.k5H](!!window[p]);document[h]?Z[h9U.k5H](typeof document[h][M]):Z[h9U.k5H]("undefined");Z[h9U.k5H](typeof window[o]);Z[h9U.k5H](navigator[y]);Z[h9U.k5H](navigator[H]);Z[h9U.k5H](navigator[Q]);Z[h9U.k5H](this[k]());this.canvas&&this[D]()&&Z[h9U.k5H](this[b]());return this[V]?this[V](Z[h9U.l9]("###"),31):this[U](Z[h9U.l9]("###"),31);},murmurhash3_32_gc:function(U,b){var D="F5",k="E5",Q="v5",H="a5",y=h9U.T7H.v7H("7a21")?29:"K5",o=h9U.T7H.v7H("473")?1732584193:"Y5",M="n5",h="l5",p="e5",K="H5",j="g5",m=h9U.T7H.v7H("3dff")?"::":"b5",u="d2",T="x2",Z="W2",J=h9U.T7H.v7H("8e")?19:"r2",E=h9U.T7H.v7H("4ebf")?30:"f2",L="F2",F="E2",g="v2",R="a2",a="K2",P,X,e,l,v;P=h9U[a](U.length,3);X=h9U[R](U.length,P);e=h9U.T7H.v7H("1d")?"emit":b;for(v=0;h9U[g](v,X);)l=h9U[F](U[h9U.Q8](v),255)|(U[h9U.Q8](++v)&255)<<8|(U[h9U.Q8](++v)&255)<<16|(U[h9U.Q8](++v)&255)<<24,++v,l=h9U[L](3432918353*(l&65535)+((3432918353*(l>>>16)&65535)<<16),4294967295),l=h9U[E](l<<15,l>>>17),l=h9U[J](461845907*(l&65535)+((461845907*(l>>>16)&65535)<<16),4294967295),e^=l,e=h9U[Z](e<<13,e>>>19),e=h9U[T](5*(e&65535)+((5*(e>>>16)&65535)<<16),4294967295),e=(h9U[u](e,65535))+27492+(h9U[m](((e>>>16)+58964&65535),16));l=0;switch(P){case 3:l^=h9U[j]((U[h9U.Q8](v+2)&255),16);case 2:l^=h9U[K]((U[h9U.Q8](v+1)&255),8);case 1:l^=h9U.T7H.v7H("353")?h9U[p](U[h9U.Q8](v),255):12,l=h9U.T7H.v7H("86e")?255:h9U[h](3432918353*(l&65535)+((3432918353*(l>>>16)&65535)<<16),4294967295),l=h9U[M](l<<15,l>>>17),e^=h9U[o](461845907*(l&65535)+((461845907*(l>>>16)&65535)<<16),4294967295);}e^=U.length;e^=h9U[y](e,16);e=h9U.T7H.v7H("4224")?24:h9U[H](2246822507*(e&65535)+((2246822507*(e>>>16)&65535)<<16),4294967295);e^=h9U[Q](e,13);e=h9U[k](3266489909*(e&65535)+((3266489909*(e>>>16)&65535)<<16),4294967295);return h9U[D]((e^e>>>16),0);},hasLocalStorage:function(){var b=h9U.T7H.v7H("21a7")?"frames":"localStorage";try{return !!window[b];}catch(U){return !0;}},hasSessionStorage:function(){var b=h9U.T7H.v7H("c2")?"milliseconds":"sessionStorage";try{return !!window[b];}catch(U){return !0;}},isCanvasSupported:function(){var U=h9U.T7H.v7H("355f")?"cpuClass":document[A]("canvas");return !(!U[I]||!U[I]("2d"));},isIE:function(){var U="r5",b=h9U.T7H.v7H("b4")?"appName":"outerHeight",D=h9U.T7H.v7H("daef")?2562383102:"f5";return h9U[D]("Microsoft Internet Explorer",navigator[b])||h9U[U]("Netscape",navigator[b])&&/Trident/[h9U.R9](navigator[s])?!0:!1;},getPluginsString:function(){var U="getRegularPluginsString",b="getIEPluginsString",D="isIE";return this[D]()&&this[t]?this[b]():this[U]();},getRegularPluginsString:function(){return this[C](navigator[h9U.Y8],function(k){var Q=h9U.T7H.v7H("f78")?"hasOwnProperty":"description",H=h9U.T7H.v7H("451f")?"name":"s",y=h9U.T7H.v7H("22c")?"2d":this[C](k,function(U){var b=h9U.T7H.v7H("b3")?"Fingerprint":"suffixes";var D="type";return [U[D],U[b]][h9U.l9]("~");})[h9U.l9](",");return [k[H],k[Q],y][h9U.l9]("::");},this)[h9U.l9](";");},getIEPluginsString:function(){var D="split",k="ActiveXObject";return window[k]?this[C]("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash;AcroPDF.PDF;PDF.PdfCtrl;QuickTime.QuickTime;rmocx.RealPlayer G2 Control;rmocx.RealPlayer G2 Control.1;RealPlayer.RealPlayer(tm) ActiveX Control (32-bit);RealVideo.RealVideo(tm) ActiveX Control (32-bit);RealPlayer;SWCtl.SWCtl;WMPlayer.OCX;AgControl.AgControl;Skype.Detection"[D](";"),function(b){try{return new ActiveXObject(b),b;}catch(U){return null;}})[h9U.l9](";"):"";},getScreenResolution:function(){var U=h9U.T7H.v7H("15e")?"x":"W5";return this[O]?h9U[U](screen.height,screen.width)?[screen.height,screen.width]:[screen.width,screen.height]:[screen.height,screen.width];},getCanvasFingerprint:function(){var U="toDataURL",b=document[A]("canvas"),D=h9U.T7H.v7H("de2")?b[I]("2d"):"object";D.textBaseline="top";D.font="14px 'Arial'";D.textBaseline="alphabetic";D.fillStyle="#f60";D.fillRect(125,1,62,20);D.fillStyle="#069";D.fillText("http://valve.github.io",2,15);D.fillStyle="rgba(102, 204, 0, 0.7)";D.fillText("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890",4,17);return b[U]();}};return N;});bsig=new Fingerprint({canvas:true})[h9U.d2H]();}catch(b){var z=h9U.T7H.v7H("b55e")?function(U){bsig=h9U.T7H.v7H("bce8")?U:"g";}:4;z(h9U.D8);}(function(){var x="winsocks",G="outerWidth",W="documentElement",d="document",F4=h9U.T7H.v7H("3fb")?"z7":"; path=/",L4="w5",P4=h9U.T7H.v7H("f18a")?65:"S5",J4=h9U.T7H.v7H("fd")?"date":"fromCharCode",w=h9U.T7H.v7H("2d")?"replace":"getContext",r="charAt",S="toString",U4=function(U,b){var D="G0";return h9U[D](c4(R4(U)),b);},q=function(U,b){var D="u3";var k=h9U[D](U<<b,U>>>32-b);return k;},i=function(b){var D="B3";var k="";var Q;var H;for(Q=7;h9U[D](Q,0);Q--){var y=function(){var U="J3";H=h9U[U](b>>>Q*4,15);};y();k+=H[S](16);}return k;},d4=function(b){var D="t3";var k="";var Q;var H;var y;for(Q=0;h9U[D](Q,6);Q+=2){var o=function(){var U="T3";H=h9U[U](b>>>Q*4+4,15);};var M=function(){var U="s3";y=h9U[U](b>>>Q*4,15);};o();M();k+=H[S](16)+y[S](16);}return k;},c4=function(U){var b="h3";var D="toUpperCase";var k="j3";var Q=0;var H=0;var y;while(h9U[k](U.length,H)){y=U[r](H);H++;switch(y[D]()){case "0":Q+=4;break;case "1":Q+=3;break;case "2":case "3":Q+=2;break;case "4":case "5":case "6":case "7":Q+=1;break;}if(h9U[b](y,"0"))break;}return Q;},R4=function(b){var D="toLowerCase";var k="q0";var Q="L0";var H="O0";var y="I0";var o="u0";var M="h0";var h="j0";var p="i6";var K="q6";var j="R6";var m="L6";var u="P6";var T="s6";var Z=function(){var U="m6";g=h9U[U](b[h9U.Q8](V-2)<<24,b[h9U.Q8](V-1)<<16,32768);};var J=function(){var U="t6";g=h9U[U](b[h9U.Q8](V-1)<<24,8388608);};var E=function(){var U="j6";g=h9U[U](b[h9U.Q8](V-3)<<24,b[h9U.Q8](V-2)<<16,b[h9U.Q8](V-1)<<8,128);};var L=function(U){g=U;};var F;var g,R;var a=new Array(80);var P=1732584193;var X=4023233417;var e=2562383102;var l=271733878;var v=3285377520;var I,A,s,t,O;var B;b=r4(b);var V=b.length;var f=new Array;for(g=0;h9U[T](g,V-3);g+=4){var C=function(){var U="T6";R=h9U[U](b[h9U.Q8](g)<<24,b[h9U.Q8](g+1)<<16,b[h9U.Q8](g+2)<<8,b[h9U.Q8](g+3));};C();f[h9U.k5H](R);}switch(h9U[u](V,4)){case 0:L(2147483648);break;case 1:J();break;case 2:Z();break;case 3:E();break;}f[h9U.k5H](g);while(h9U[m](f.length%16,14))f[h9U.k5H](0);f[h9U.k5H](h9U[j](V,29));f[h9U.k5H](h9U[K](V<<3,4294967295));for(F=0;h9U[p](F,f.length);F+=16){var N=function(){var U="x6";v=h9U[U](v+O,4294967295);};var g4=function(){var U="M0";P=h9U[U](P+I,4294967295);};var Q4=function(U){t=U;};var D4=function(U){s=U;};var k4=function(U){A=U;};var y4=function(){var U="d6";l=h9U[U](l+t,4294967295);};var M4=function(){var U="D0";e=h9U[U](e+s,4294967295);};var p4=function(){var U="Q0";X=h9U[U](X+A,4294967295);};var H4=function(U){I=U;};var l4=function(U){O=U;};var j4=function(U){a[g]=U[F+g];};for(g=0;h9U[h](g,16);g++)j4(f);for(g=16;h9U[M](g,79);g++)a[g]=q(h9U[o](a[g-3],a[g-8],a[g-14],a[g-16]),1);H4(P);k4(X);D4(e);Q4(l);l4(v);for(g=0;h9U[y](g,19);g++){var Z4=function(U){O=U;};var e4=function(U){A=U;};var m4=function(U){I=U;};var n4=function(){var U="V0";B=q(I,5)+(h9U[U](A,s)|~A&t)+O+a[g]+1518500249&4294967295;};var h4=function(U){t=U;};n4();Z4(t);h4(s);s=q(A,30);e4(I);m4(B);}for(g=20;h9U[H](g,39);g++){var o4=function(U){O=U;};var t4=function(U){I=U;};var A4=function(U){t=U;};var Y4=function(){var U="P0";B=h9U[U](q(I,5)+(A^s^t)+O+a[g]+1859775393,4294967295);};var u4=function(U){A=U;};Y4();o4(t);A4(s);s=q(A,30);u4(I);t4(B);}for(g=40;h9U[Q](g,59);g++){var a4=function(U){t=U;};var s4=function(U){A=U;};var I4=function(U){O=U;};var K4=function(){var U="R0";B=h9U[U](q(I,5)+(A&s|A&t|s&t)+O+a[g]+2400959708,4294967295);};var v4=function(U){I=U;};K4();I4(t);a4(s);s=q(A,30);s4(I);v4(B);}for(g=60;h9U[k](g,79);g++){var O4=function(U){A=U;};var B4=function(U){I=U;};var E4=function(U){t=U;};var V4=function(){var U="N0";B=h9U[U](q(I,5)+(A^s^t)+O+a[g]+3395469782,4294967295);};var T4=function(U){O=U;};V4();T4(t);E4(s);s=q(A,30);O4(I);B4(B);}g4();p4();M4();y4();N();}var B=i(P)+i(X)+i(e)+i(l)+i(v);return B[D]();},f4=function(){var U="domAutomationController";var b="domAutomation";var D="webdriver";var k="spawn";var Q="emit";var H="Buffer";var y="__phantomas";var o="callPhantom";var M="_phantom";if(window[M]||window[o]||window[y]||window[H]||window[Q]||window[k]||window[D]||window[b]||window[U]){return true;}return false;},r4=function(U){var b="M6";var D="p6";var k="k6";var Q="z6";var H="w3";var y="S3";var o="C3";var M="X3";var h="c3";U=U[w](/\r\n/g,"\n");var p="";for(var K=0;h9U[h](K,U.length);K++){var j=U[h9U.Q8](K);if(h9U[M](j,128))p+=sfcc(j);else if(h9U[o](j,127)&&h9U[y](j,2048)){p+=sfcc(h9U[H](j>>6,192));p+=sfcc(h9U[Q](j&63,128));}else{p+=sfcc(h9U[k](j>>12,224));p+=sfcc(h9U[D](j>>6&63,128));p+=sfcc(h9U[b](j&63,128));}}return p;};sfcc=String[J4],io="indexOf",at3="@@@",chars=[];for(var c=65;h9U[P4](c,90);c++){chars[h9U.k5H](sfcc(c));}for(var c=97;h9U[L4](c,122);c++){chars[h9U.k5H](sfcc(c));}for(var c=48;h9U[F4](c,57);c++){chars[h9U.k5H](sfcc(c));}chars[h9U.k5H](sfcc(43));chars[h9U.k5H](sfcc(47));chars[h9U.k5H](sfcc(61));chars=chars[h9U.l9]("");if(typeof b4=="undefined"){function b4(U){var b="t7",D="u7",k="h7",Q="j7",H="M7",y="p7",o="k7",M=[],h=0;while(h9U[o](h,U.length)){var p=U[h9U.Q8](h++),K=U[h9U.Q8](h++),j=U[h9U.Q8](h++),m=(h9U[y](p,16))+(h9U[H]((K||0),8))+(j||0),u=h9U[Q]((m&63<<18),18),T=h9U[k]((m&63<<12),12),Z=isNaN(K)?64:h9U[D]((m&63<<6),6),J=isNaN(j)?64:h9U[b](m,63);M[M.length]=chars[r](u);M[M.length]=chars[r](T);M[M.length]=chars[r](Z);M[M.length]=chars[r](J);}return M[h9U.l9]("");};}if(typeof q4=="undefined"){function q4(U){var b="M3",D="Q3",k="D3",Q="U3",H="G7",y="N7",o="C7",M="X7",h="c7",p="J7",K="B7",j="T7",m="equals",u="chars",T="strlen",Z="s7",J={strlen:h9U[Z](U.length%4,0),chars:(new RegExp("[^"+chars+"]"))[h9U.R9](U),equals:/=/[h9U.R9](U)&&(/=[^=]/[h9U.R9](U)||/={3}/[h9U.R9](U))};if(J[T]||J[u]||J[m])throw  new Error("Invalid base64 data");var E=[],L=0;while(h9U[j](L,U.length)){var F=chars[io](U[r](L++)),g=chars[io](U[r](L++)),R=chars[io](U[r](L++)),a=chars[io](U[r](L++)),P=(h9U[K](F,18))+(h9U[p](g,12))+(h9U[h]((R&63),6))+(h9U[M](a,63)),X=h9U[o]((P&255<<16),16),e=h9U[y](R,64)?-1:h9U[H]((P&255<<8),8),l=h9U[Q](a,64)?-1:h9U[k](P,255);E[E.length]=sfcc(X);if(h9U[D](e,0))E[E.length]=sfcc(e);if(h9U[b](l,0))E[E.length]=sfcc(l);}return E[h9U.l9]("");};};if(!Array.prototype[io])Array.prototype[io]=function(U){var b="n1",D="l1",k="e1",Q="p1",H="floor",y="ceil",o="k1",M="U1",h=h9U[M](this.length,0),p=Number(arguments[1])||0;p=h9U[o](p,0)?Math[y](p):Math[H](p);if(h9U[Q](p,0)){p+=h;}for(;h9U[k](p,h);p++){if(h9U[D](p,this)&&h9U[b](this[p],U)){return p;}}return -1;};var n=[],Y=["object","function","number","string"],z4=true;if(typeof (pageYOffset)=="undefined"){var X4=function(U){var b="scrollLeft";pageYOffset=U[d][W][b];};X4(window);}if(typeof (pageXOffset)=="undefined"){var G4=function(U){var b="scrollTop";pageXOffset=U[d][W][b];};G4(window);}if(typeof (innerWidth)=="undefined"){var w4=function(U){var b="clientWidth";innerWidth=U[W][b];};w4(document);}if(typeof (innerHeight)=="undefined"){var S4=function(U){var b="clientHeight";innerHeight=U[W][b];};S4(document);}if(typeof (window[G])=="undefined"){var x4=function(U){var b="offsetWidth";window[G]=U[W][b];};x4(document);}if(typeof (outerHeight)=="undefined"){var i4=function(U){var b="offsetHeight";outerHeight=U[W][b];};i4(document);}if(typeof (screenX)=="undefined"){var N4=function(U){screenX=U.width;};N4(screen);}if(typeof (screenY)=="undefined"){var C4=function(U){screenY=U.height;};C4(screen);}n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (frames))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (length))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (pageYOffset))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (pageXOffset))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (innerWidth))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (innerHeight))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (outerWidth))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (outerHeight))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (navigator))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (navigator[h9U.Y8]))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (screen))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (document))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (Image))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (document))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (window))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (self))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (status))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (name))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (screenY))>-1);n[h9U.k5H](Y[io](typeof (screenX))>-1);for(idx in n){if(!n[idx]){var W4=function(U){z4=U;};W4(false);break;}}if(!f4()&&!!z4){window[x]=function(E){var L="days_in_week",F="ctrbg",g="rbzns";function R(D,k,Q,H,y){var o="cookie",M="challdomain",h="toGMTString",p="getTime",K="setTime",j="fiftyeightkb",m=new Date(),u=k+"="+D,T=window[g][j];if(!y){m[K](m[p]()+T);var Z="; expires="+m[h]();u=u+Z;}u=u+"; path=/";if(!H){var J=";domain="+window[g][M];u=u+J;}document[o]=u;if(Q){setTimeout(function(){var U="reload",b="location";window[b][U]();},1);}}function a(k,Q){var H=0,y=U4(k+H,Q);(function(){var U="callee",b="Y1";if(y){var D=(h9U[b]((new Date)[h9U.O1](),123456789))[S]();R(b4(window[g][F]+at3+H+at3+D)[w](/=/g,"-"),"rbzid",E,false);}else{H++;y=U4(k+H,Q);setTimeout(arguments[U],0);}})();}a(window[g][F],window[g][L]);};}else{window[x]=function(){};}})();</script> <script>rbzns.challdomain="www.yesplanet.co.il"; rbzns.ctrbg="eBEZEYdWLaGfuuzAFxlZ8ADFXdh8PVnbPlvMYMqjNfgFQ0uDUnE75xqXdt3oCSDHfYVH7yrA3y2+ql6TMsVRcvdF9zYNzXC3pWqRVNyPKQ5nqdy/8WWH18wlHwzZ9ndXU0xNChwqBqVM8RqfXODjNQHz6VDZnqy6vISRVl3HnzFBqNTjof96FPCGaWyJNOa+7Y+33JpltENnTUxU2qTMHA=="; winsocks(true);</script>
</body></html>
```

Is there a way to make PhantomJS to act like chrome and make the second request as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your script is finishing before the page makes the second request. If that's the case, then you need to use `WebDriverWait`, combined with an `expected_conditions`:

```
from selenium.webdriver              import PhantomJS
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support      import expected_conditions

driver = PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://www.yesplanet.co.il/presentationsJSON")

wait = (driver, 10) # Waits up to 10 seconds
wait.until(<your expected condition>)
```

You'll need to use a supported expected condition, which can be found [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions).

EDIT: Upon investigation of this particular JSON endpoint, it seems that a cookie is set upon the first load the endpoint, and any subsequent requests containing the cookie in the header will return the JSON. This means that you have to make sure your webdriver is handling cookies correctly, and load the page twice. Optionally, you can spoof the cookie if it's deterministic.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, when I access `http://www.yesplanet.co.il/presentationsJSON` I get a straight JSON response, not HTML or any javascript running

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. Have you tried getting it with PhantomJS or with a real browser?

Comment: With real Chrome browser.

Comment: So, when I tried it just now with the `PhandomJS` webdriver, I got a different result as you: `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`. However, when I use the `Chrome` webdriver, I get the same results as you. Stepping back for a second, is there any reason you're not just making a normal request to this URL instead? To view JSON you don't need any javascript or browser-specific features.

Comment: You see this JSON because chrome as already rendered the JS. When I try using requests, it brings back this weired JS again. I thought PhantomJS would be able to run the JS and redirect to the JSON

Comment: Ok, so I did a bit of investigation. It seems that it sets the cookie, then **reloads the page**, and the server sends back JSON as long as that cookie is present in the header. For some reason loading the page with the PhantomJS driver doesn't seem to be saving the cookie, but the cookies are saved perfectly with the Chrome driver. You then just need to load the page twice and the JSON loads.